# How shall I convert String to Writable object in my Hadoop Mapper

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, twitter, hbase

This is a very crazy problem hitting me since a few hours.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am not able to

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      if (!value.toString().equals("")) {



          Gson gson = new Gson();
          Boolean flag = true;
          System.out.println("000000000"); 
          while(flag){
              Text tweetId = new Text();
              Tweet tweet = gson.fromJson(value.toString(), Tweet.class);
              tweetId.set(tweet.getRetweetStatus().getUser().getId().toString());
              System.out.println("Tweet objects:" + tweet.toString());
              System.out.println("ParentUserId:" + tweetId);
              context.write(tweetId, tweet);
              flag = false;
          }
          Text tweetId = new Text();
          Tweet tweet = gson.fromJson(value.toString(), Tweet.class);
          tweetId.set(tweet.getUser().getId().toString());
          String tweetReverse = (Object) tweet.getRetweetStatus().getUser().getId();

          System.out.println("Reverse::");
          System.out.println("Tweet objects:" + tweetReverse);
          System.out.println("ParentUserId:" + tweetId);

          context.write(tweetId, tweetReverse);
      }
    }
```

I want to convert the String object 'tweetReverse' to Writable so that I can use it the context.write function.

Is this even possible?

What shall I do if not convert?

If I change the generic type to String, then also I get problems in the class which extends Writable to reading and writing values.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I have a feeling that all you need is just

```
context.write(tweetId, new Text(tweetReverse));
```

That is, you just create a new Text object (which implements Writable) and pass a String in the constructor.